# What rule can I give to authors who start sentences with "-ing" words when it's inappropriate?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

I work as an editor and I've found that many writers (usually novices) inappropriately begin sentences with "-ing" words (as opposed to appropriately beginning sentences with "-ing" words. It's a common problem in my field. Here are two consecutive examples from an essay I'm currently editing:

> 1. Determining a medium of instruction in education is driven by political, social and economic forces.
> 2. Championing a foreign language has disadvantaged speakers of indigenous languages.

I know how to correct these sentences - "The determination of..." etc. - but what rule should I give my author?

Comment: Telling them, "Don't listen to me when I tell you it's incorrect to start a sentence with an '-ing' word." might be a good place to start.

Comment: Related question, [When is it acceptable to start a sentence with an “-ing” word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156226/when-is-it-acceptable-to-start-a-sentence-with-an-ing-word). As I commented to your answer to the linked question, please take the tour and visit our Help Center.

Comment: So you prefer "The championation of foreign languages has disadvantaged speakers of indigenous languages"?

Comment: Your examples sound stilted and bureaucratic, but your proposed solution makes that problem even worse.

Comment: @Jim The OP isn't saying that we shouldn't start sentences with *-ing* words. They're asking about how to advise people who are doing this *inappropriately*, as in the OP's examples.

Comment: @Jim Have had an edit to make it clear.

Comment: @ThePhoton "The championing of foreign languages has disadvantaged speakers of indigenous languages" Seems ok to me.

Comment: Hey, if there exists no such rule in the entirety of English, this could be the perfect chance to come up with a law named after you! ;)

Comment: Tell them to turn the sentence around and if it still makes sense to use the “-ing” word then use it otherwise change it.  For example: “*Political, social and economic forces drive the determining of a medium of instruction...*”.   Clearly “*the determination*” is appropriate here.

Comment: If you want a rule for writers, tell them that using an "-ing" word to start a sentence is a signal that you may be about to write a run-on sentence, or at least one that's unnecessarily awkward.

Comment: (But if you tell them to not start sentences with \*ing words they may take that the wrong way.)

Answer (score 5):

I understood both sentences. They are communicating effectively. If you wish to "correct," them, I suggest that you be clear about the purely stylistic motivation for the changes. Sentences that sound awkward are not grammatically incorrect, nor are they a failure to communicate. They are simply sub-optimal for the chosen reader/listener.

Answer (score -1):

The rule you should give them is to use the simplest word that communicates clearly what needs to be communicated.

Taking just the first sentence (I'm sure you can extend the lesson to the second):

1. The word you need here at the beginning is *choosing*. You could certainly replace it with *Choice*, but *choosing* is the process, and it is the process that is “driven by” (I’d prefer *heavily influenced by*, or *informed by*) the socio-econo-political-etc. milieu.
2. If you really hate *—ing* words, use *Choice of …*.
3. The single largest nastiness in this sentence is *instruction in education*, which while it’s attempting to be precise, sounds like a horrible tautology as phrased. One or the other should be sufficient to get the point across.

I would personally suggest something along the lines of

> *Choice of instruction medium is subject to social, economic and political pressures*

but that’s just me.

One final comment: this *could* be the result of trying too hard to paraphrase “sources” using nothing but a thesaurus and a *smalllllll* aubergine…